# Is Ichigo technically dead?

Tags: bleach

When Ichigo is being trained by Kisuke his second lesson involves Ichigo's Chain of Fate being cut, and in order for him to avoid becoming a Hollow he has to become a Soul Reaper.

After he gets out of the pit he was stuck in now with his own Soul Reaper Powers, Kisuke then begins his third lesson which is a fight. Between the start of the second lesson and the end of the third lesson there doesn't seem to be a point where they repair Ichigo's Chain of Fate (if it's even possible).

So is Ichigo technically dead because his Chain of Fate was cut?

Answer (score 4):

I would say yes.

It does not interfere with the "not letting the main character die" rule, because the main part of the story plays in the world of the dead (soul society).

So I ask if the concept of "death and alive" even does apply to bleach? He might be dead ever since he first became a Shinigami or, as you described, as soon as his chain got destroyed.

As for the time he is in his body and interacts with the world of the living, he might just go back into his body or as other Shinigami enter a Gigai (artificial body).

I sadly have no prove for this claim, it is my theory.

Answer (score 3):

I personally feel that these are just certain events in the manga which make the reader feel that its happened. 
But mangaka's are such beings that they can create their own logic and make dead people alive!
Logically if you think, then Killing the main person of a story which is going so great, can have a highly positive or negative impact on the sales of a manga.
The writer is just creating such events that generate these kind of thoughts in the readers mind!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it in the most basic way: the answer should be no. Remember, many people can see Ichigo (not just the special ones who can see the dead). They don't show Ichigo getting into a fake body for his day to day life at any point. Only leaving it for Kon in the earlier parts of the series.

Recall the 17 months after Ichigo did not have powers (around the Fullbringer Arc) that everyone could see and interact with him. If that could happen, he should not be viewed as dead.

Take it with a grain of salt, remember that the author/creator Kubo Tite has been inconsistent with some things in the past and gets sloppy with  his writing from time to time.

Comment: Well, a shinigami in a Gigai could interact with the living, which is exactly what several did. Ichigo could just be a special case where his gigai is infact a real human body, his old one. Then again, we dont even know if Urahara swapped out ichigos real body for a Gigai, since normally the body dies when the Chain is severed. He could be an exception though because Shinigami do not have such chains, though maybe Pluses cant go into bodies without the chain, but were keep warping back to did ichigos body survive or not, which so far is still unknown.